# Prisma: User `user` was denied access on the database `db.public`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am getting

```
Error: P1010: User `blog_user` was denied access on the database `blog_db.public`
```

When I try to migrate `Prisma` schema for the first time in a local `PostgreSQL` database running on `Fedora`.

The following is my `DATABASE_URL` in `.env` file.

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://blog_user:blog_pswd@localhost:5432/blog_db
```

The following is the output I get with `\l`.

```
 Name    |   Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |    Access privileges    
-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------
 blog_db   | blog_user | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =Tc/blog_user          +
           |           |          |             |             |            |                 | blog_user=CTc/blog_user
```

The following is my `pg_hba.conf` file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# host    all             all             192.168.1.1/24            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

The following are queries I have already tried.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE blog_db TO blog_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO blog_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO blog_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO blog_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE blog_db TO blog_user;
GRANT pg_write_all_data TO blog_user;
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO blog_user;
```

Comment: This `blog_db.public` looks like something is combining the database name `blog_db` with the schema name `public`. And the error is correct there is no database named `blog_db.public`. You will need to look at Prisma code to see what it is doing. Might help to look at Postgres logs and see what the commands are that are hitting the database.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on Github. After a lot of tries this comment solved it for me: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4571#issuecomment-1220760128

Basically I defined shadow database url in my .env file. Like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Also, I had some "-" in my user and DB names, also replaced it with "_". I dont know if it was also causing some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `METHOD` from `ident` to `md5` for `IPv6` solved it for me.

My `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# host    all             all             192.168.1.1/24            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```